# Can I search Google for the href link in an anchor tag?

Tags: html, search, anchor

In other words, if there are pages out on the web with anchor tags saying, for example:

```html
<a href="www.MySite.com/this_page.html">Interesting photo</a>
```

Can I search for "this_page.html" and find pages that link to that page on my site? I seem to be able to search only for "Interesting photo", the shown text in the link.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=find%20websites%20that%20link%20to%20your%20site

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following google search: `www.mysite.com/this_page.html -site:www.mysite.com` To find webpages there links to your website `-site:www.mysite.com` exclude your own website.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a "backlink-checker"
for the main site, but it won't reference 
individual pages (free versions anyway, paid version will have different feature sets).